# Floating action button issue

Tags: html, css, reactjs, angular

Included Example to what i have in the Floating action button

how to make the content of the Floating action button take their position dynamic without using >>>   transform: translateY(-250%);

because this is a fixed way

any help so i can fix this issue

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

```js
  $('#FABMG').click(function () {
            $('#FABMG').toggleClass('show');
            $('#overlay').toggleClass('show');
            $('.nav').toggleClass('show');
        });
```

```css
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 1.3;
        }

        #image {
            z-index: 0;
        }

        #image img {
            display: block;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 820px;
        }

        #text {
            z-index: 0;
            padding: 18px 38px;
        }

        #overlay {
            z-index: 2;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.7);
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
            will-change: opacity;
        }

        #overlay.show {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
        }

        #FABMG {
            z-index: 10;
            position: fixed;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            bottom: 10%;
            right: 5%;
            background-color: #94C03D;
            width: 56px;
            height: 56px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            cursor: pointer;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.3);
            transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        }

        #FABMG .icon-bar {
            display: block;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            width: 22px;
            height: 2px;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        }

        #FABMG .icon-bar+.icon-bar {
            margin-top: 4px;
        }

        .nav {
            z-index: 9;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 10.5%;
            right: 5.5%;
            width: 48px;
            height: 48px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            visibilty: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
        }

        .material-icons {
            font-size: 24px;
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
        }

        #settings.show {
            transform: translateY(-125%);
        }

        #thumb.show {
            transform: translateY(-250%);
        }

        #create.show {
            transform: translateY(-375%);
        }

        #share.show {
            transform: translateY(-500%);
        }

        #FABMG.show {
            box-shadow: 7px 7px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
        }

        #FABMG.show #wrapper {
            transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
            transform: rotateZ(90deg);
        }

        #FABMG.show #one {
            transform: translateY(6px) rotateZ(45deg) scaleX(0.9);
        }

        #FABMG.show #thr {
            transform: translateY(-6px) rotateZ(-45deg) scaleX(0.9);
        }

        #FABMG.show #two {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .nav.show {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

    <div id="FABMG">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <span class="icon-bar" id="one"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar" id="two"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar" id="thr"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav" id="settings">
        <i class="material-icons">settings</i>
    </div>
    <div class="nav" id="thumb">
        <i class="material-icons">thumb_up</i>
    </div>
    <div class="nav" id="create">
        <i class="material-icons">create</i>
    </div>
    <div class="nav" id="share">
        <i class="material-icons">share</i>
    </div>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue needs to be contained directly inside your question, do not just dump the code onto an external platform.

Comment: You can not have it _fully_ "dynamic", if you want to keep the effect exactly as it currently is. All those elements are fix positioned at the exact same location - so you _need_ to specify, how much you want to move them. And if you left them in normal flow in some wrapper element to begin with (so that they would automatically position one below the other) - then you would have the same problem, only in the other direction, you would need to know how much exactly you'd need to move them _down_, to "hide" them behind the button.

Comment: i want the same direction and the same design but to be dynamic when i add new button and when i remove button the come close to each others again